# How ti initialise some property to the response when the subscribe method is successfully done - in the complete method?

Tags: angular, rxjs

There is a api post method that is failing sometimes.If it is failing i am showing error message to the page. But sometimes when there is error on the api, it is still getting in the next method and then i have errors. I want to be sure when there is not error,so on the complete method to initialise my property on the response that is coming. My code looks like this.

```
 this.attService.postUser(user).subscribe((response: any) => {

      this.postRequestResponse = response;
      this.selectedServiceSpeedsArr.push(this.selectedServiceSpeed);
      let index = this.selectedAttService[0].serviceSpeeds.findIndex(item => item.id == event.id);
    
    }, (err) => {
      this.makeQuoteErrorMessage = 'Something went wrong.Please try again';
    }, () => {
      console.log("success");      
      //can i done something like this ? 
      myProperty = response;
    })
  }
```

Comment: Could you please clarify "_when there is error on the api, it is still getting in the next method_"? When the HTTP request fails, the error callback is triggered directly, the `next` callback won't be triggered. Do you mean you get the response but there is some error in the response?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, as you see here :

```
 export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

 ngOnInit() {

  let result = this.http.get(<YOUR_URL>);

  result.subscribe(
     res => {
      // this is your response with no errors
     },
     err => {
      // here you handle your errors
     },
     () => {
      // here is the finally block where you can do things either you got errors or not
     }
  );
 }
}
```

You may wanna give [this one](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/) a shot, good luck!

Comment: Hi, users with enough reputation can see deleted posts and could clearly see that you've posted the same answer again that you've deleted before. The same comments from your deleted posts apply here as well. While your answer explain how passing basic callbacks to subscriptions work, it doesn't clarify OP's question.

Comment: Hi there, man I'm so confused right now, think I'm giving a hand here though, btw the deleted answer. sorry if I caused any problems.

Comment: No you haven't cause any issues. I am pointing out the answer might not help OP solve their issue and that people with enough rep can see deleted posts from other users. And right now your deleted post and the current post are exactly the same.

Comment: Yeah I see, cause I undeleted it, edited it and delete it again (sorry I'm kinda new here). Thanks tho I'll consider that in my future answers, best regards.